# How to detect a negative integer in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using ServerValue.increment in Flutter to update an inventory amount in Firebase. It is a nice solution when my users are offline, but I need to fix the folowing case:

1. The user 1 reads the inventory of 40 (in example) and inmediately goes offline
2. The user 2 reads the same inventory (40) and spend 10, then the online inventory is updated to 30
3. The user 1 spends 35 (less than 40). When he/she goes online again the inventory is updated to -5 (30 - 35)

I would like to detect this negative number to execute a procedure. How can I detect it in Firebase?

I'm using ServerValue.increment in this way:

```
db.child('quantityInStock')
    .set(ServerValue.increment(-quantityToReduce.round()));
```

**How can I detect when quantityInStock ends up being a negative number in order to execute a new procedure automatically?**

Answer (score 1):

If the new value depends on the existing value in the way you describe, you have two options:

1. Use security rules to ensure the write operations is only allowed when there's enough inventory.

   ```
   ".write": "newData.val() >= 0"
   ```
2. Use a transaction to ensure that your client can actively check the current value, to determine the new value.

   ```
   dataRef.runTransaction((MutableData transaction) async{
     if (transaction.value >= 40) {
       transaction.value = transaction.value - 40;
     }
     return transaction;
   });
   ```

Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.

For example: using security rules in your scenario with an offline user may prevent your application code from knowing the write was rejected, as completion listeners are not persisted across app restarts.

Using a transaction you won't have this problem, but in that case your app will only work when the user is connected to the database. Transactions don't work when the user is offline.

Comment: Thanks @puf. I need to work with offline users, then I think the first approach is better. Then, If I implemment security rules, how can I execute an action when the user comes back online and the write is rejected?. I mean something like... If (write is rejected because there are not enough inventory) {then to set the inventory in 0 and to do something with the missing ammount (-5)}

Comment: As said: you can attach a completion listener to catch write results, but completion listeners are not persisted on app restarts. Honestly: since you want to perform a different write based on the actual value in the database, I'd be more inclined to map it to a transaction.

Comment: Alternative: don't have the client update the quantity directly, but have it write its mutation to the database. So: the client write a record that says it wants to get 40 items from a certain type, and then you have a Cloud Function process those records.

Comment: Mmmmm... How can I evaluate this alternative?